# GScatter addon showing python error

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have tried reinstalling the addon but it didn't work. It occours whenever I am trying to scatter selected object, or to install anything in its library. Here's an SS[image]

Comment: Hello, are you sure you're using a version that's supposed to work with Blender 3.5 ?

Comment: nodes is a collection and if one references into an empty collection (nodes['stringRef']) -- assuming it is not empty -- an exception is thrown.  GScatter appears to have a bug to be fixed.  look for some feedback on [their site](https://www.graswald3d.com/gscatter)